# Invoking Custom Directive Processor from a Csharp(.cs) file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c-preprocessor, t4

I am trying to invoke a custom Directive Processor in a CSharp program written in  Visual Studio and I came across this article : ["Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Directive Processor"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126542.aspx)  where we can do that. But here the code is written in a T4 template File . Is there any other way to invoke a directive processor from a (.cs)Charp file directly ?

Comment: Directive processors are plugins to T4.  I don't get what a non-T4 solution would use a directive processor for?

Comment: Yes i understand. I need such a feature on a normal c# class file.. I couldn't find it any where. 

Basically i want to build and invoke a custom Processor directive for a normal c# class file .

Comment: It sounds like you want to intercept the C# compiler's language directives here?  The answer in that case is no ,they are not extensible.

Comment: without seeing some sort of code example I am not sure what you are attempting to achieve but I will throw this [link](https://www.postsharp.net/) out there, post sharp or something like it might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you need to apply transformations to your code using a directive processor:

1. Set build action of original CS file to "None".
2. Add T4 file which loads the original CS file and outputs the transformed file.

If all you need is to modify your CS file and the directive processor is yet to written, you can skip writing it and apply all transformations directly in T4 file.